# Python 2 Recursive function returns previously executed value

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I started writing some simple code that supposed to end up being a crossword puzzle solver. In the process, I've used a recursive function. The output is really confusing me. Here's the code:

```
def checkMatcher(totalRows, prevCoor, count):
    print(count)
    if count < 3:
        for coor in totalRows[count]:
            if (prevCoor[0] == coor[0] or prevCoor[0] == coor[0] + 1 or prevCoor[0] == coor[0] - 1) and (prevCoor[1] == coor[1] or prevCoor[1] == coor[1] + 1 or prevCoor[1] == coor[1] - 1):
                count += 1
                checkMatcher(totalRows, coor, count)
    return count

letterCoordinates = [
    [(1,1),(9,7),(13,44),(9,99)],
    [(1,2),(7,3),(12,12),(10,10)],
    [(1,3),(8,88),(7,4),(82,11)]
]

#for firstletterCoor in letterCoordinates[0]:
count = checkMatcher(letterCoordinates, (1,1), 1)
print("Returned Count is " + str(count))
```

The output ends up being:

```
1
2
3
Returned Count is 2
```

My question is, why isn't the returned count 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `count` equals `1`, it gets incremented by 1 and then passed to the recursive call (which prints `2` and makes a recursive call with `3` which then prints `3`). When control gets back to the first call, `count` is still `2`.

You need to take into account the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: Ah I see, looks like I just needed a return on the recursive call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the recursive call:

```
checkMatcher(totalRows, coor, count)
```

is disregarding the return value.